# SSL handshake error - log domain name with Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, logging

Is it possible to extend SSL handshake error log to determine which domain was requested? Now I get log in the following format without any information about domain:

```
2023/02/27 12:27:58 [info] 60011#60011: *302628755 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher) while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```